# How do I use the response from a postasync call?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, httpresponsemessage

I have a webApi set up that has a PostStudent method. The API call works fine and creates a new student in the DB, but I can't get it to return the value in the response body. I have tried returning Ok(newStudent) and Created("~/api/poststudent", newStudent) but neither of them have returned the newStudent value that I need.

I have gone through all of the response and can't find the actual newStudent object. Is it there and I am just missing it or do I have a problem with my code?

This is the PostStudent method from the API;

```
var newStudent = new Student
{
  studentId = nextStudentId,
  studentFirstName = studentEntry.StudentFirstName,
  studentLastName = studentEntry.StudentLastName,
  studentDOB = studentEntry.StudentDob,
  studentEmergencyContactName = studentEntry.StudentEmergencyContactName,
  studentEmergencyContactNum = studentEntry.StudentEmergencyContactNum,
  ticketNumber = studentEntry.TicketNumber
};

db.Student.Add(newStudent);

try
{
  db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateException)
{
  if (StudentExists(newStudent.studentId))
    return BadRequest("That student id already exists");
    throw;
}
return Ok(newStudent.studentId);
// return Created("~/api/poststudent", newStudent);     
}
```

This is where I call postasync and try to save the response body;

```
var response = client.PostAsync("api/poststudent", content);
return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ToString();
```

And this is where I want to use the value;

```
var newStudentId = controller.PostStudent(studentFirstName, studentLastName, studentDob, ticketNumber);
var url = "~/AddGuardian/AddGuardian/" + newStudentId;
Response.Redirect(url);
```

I hope someone can help me. I never thought redirecting to another page would be so damn hard!

Cheers.

Comment: Please add context to these 3 snippets showing excepts from web api controllers and web api client code - at least file and method names. Clear code structure helps readers understand your code. I do not understand how control flow reaches third snippets. I start an answer linking to official tutorials.

Comment: it is especially unclear to me what you expect from the third snippet. Usually redirecting code in ASP.NET MVC applications is done using RedirectToAction()

Answer (score 1):

You're not *awaiting* the `async` calls:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("api/poststudent", content);
return (await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).ToString();
```

Comment: I did have await in there but it was hanging for some reason. I only removed them out of frustration but it started working after that.

Comment: @Schming: It started working after you removed the `await` keywords?  That doesn't seem likely.  But even if so, then what isn't working?

Comment: Nah I didn't understand it either, though I am only very new to asynchronous programming. When I create a new student, the db will assign a new studentId. I want to use that id as a parameter in the redirect url.

Comment: I can't find the id anywhere in the response when I am debugging, so I can't work out how to complete my url

Comment: @Schming: *Should* the ID be in the response?  The server-side code shows it only used in the URL of the redirect.  That would be in the headers of the response, not the content.

Comment: I assumed that anything in the brackets of an Ok() or Created() would come back in the content

Comment: @Schming: That may often be the case, but that's not what you're using.  You're using `Response.Redirect(url)`.

Comment: I have just posted my api method. All I need is the studentId saved to a variable so that I can create the redirect url "~/AddGuardian/AddGuardian/ " + NewStudentId

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 official tutorials for quickstarting a ASP.NET WebApi project.

- [Using Web API 2 with Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/)
- [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

I want to recommend to work through these. If you find your application is doing things wrong, fix your application towards these samples. If your requirements differ from what is given in the samples, you can emphasize on this in your question.